# Synonymize typo tag [xammp]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

There are 35 question tagged [xammp](/questions/tagged/xammp) which actually should be tagged [xampp](/questions/tagged/xampp). Either we should synonymize those tags (seems lots of people do that wrong) or at least burninate at so people don't start typing "xam" and click the wrong tag...

[xampp](/questions/tagged/xampp) has about 2500 questions.

Comment: [Looks like it is a *very* common typo](https://www.google.com/search?q=xammp)